# Email class Method incorrect error

Tags: email, error, apex-email-service, method

My Email class is getting a compilation error as below. Can someone please help?

**Error**

```
 Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setToAddresses(String)
```

**Apex class snippet**

```
      String addresses; 
      // activeUser = [Select Email From User where Username = : UserInfo.getUserName()];
       for (User u : [Select Email From User where Username = : UserInfo.getUserName()]) {     

            addresses+=':'+ u.Email;

            }
         String[] toAddresses = addresses.split(':', 0); 

            // Sets the paramaters of the email
            email.setSubject( 'Email Generated Blank Forms');
            email.setToAddresses( toAddresses[0] );
            email.setPlainTextBody( 'Please find attached forms');

            email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

            // Sends the email
            Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});   

            return null;
```

Comment: Whenever you face such an error, you can check the documentation and confirm the method signature. Documentation helps a lot when such errors are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 email.setToAddresses( toAddresses[0] );
```

You need to pass here list of string not string.

try this

```
List<string> addresses =  new List<string>(); 
      // activeUser = [Select Email From User where Username = : UserInfo.getUserName()];
       for (User u : [Select Email From User where Username = : UserInfo.getUserName()]) {     

            addresses.add( u.Email);

            }
//or can do this addresses.add( userinfo.getuserEmail()); don't need any soql

            // Sets the paramaters of the email
            email.setSubject( 'Email Generated Blank Forms');
            email.setToAddresses( addresses );
            email.setPlainTextBody( 'Please find attached forms');

            email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

            // Sends the email
            Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});   

            return null;
```

Comment: toAddresses[0] will give a single address and not multiple addresses. So this will also throw an error. It should be email.setToAddresses(toAddresses); where toAddresses is a list of String.

Comment: @Azinq check my answer.

Comment: @TusharSharma   Thanks , but I am not receiving the emails with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );`

**setToAddresses** method accepts List and here you are passing String.

**Ref:** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setToAddresses